# How to execute cmd of print command using C#?

Tags: c#

I want to run in C# the command:

```
PRINT /D:\\rshprt04\p-RSH108 C:\Users\o-tsoudry\Files\Tehila.txt
```

I tried the next code:

```cs
string result = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
string exception;

try
{
    startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    string fileName = @"C:\Users\o-tsoudry\Files\Tehila.txt";
    string printer_Name = @"\p-RSH108 ";
    startInfo.Arguments = "PRINT /D:\\rshprt04" + printer_Name + fileName;
    process.StartInfo = startInfo;
    process.Start();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    exception = ex.Message;
}
```

But it's not working.
When I stand on the process in debugging I see the error:

> ExitCode = 'proc.ExitCode' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'

Any idea?

Comment: What are you trying to do? [print](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/orphan-topics/ws.10/cc772773(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) can only print text files on serial or parallel printers. It expects device names like COM1 and LPT1.

Comment: In Windows, the `Print` menu you see in a document's context menu is a specific Shell verb that opens a document's registered application and sends it the `Print` verb.

Comment: Yes, I want to print text file to specific printer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Below :

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
psi.FileName = fileName;
psi.Arguments = "\"" + PrinterName + "\"";
psi.Verb = "PrintTo";
Process.Start(psi).WaitForExit();
```

Comment: That's actually the *correct* answer for printing *any* file on Windows since Windows 95. Not the DOS PRINT command

Comment: First thank you for your answer. Second where you write the printer name?

Comment: I need to print to special printer of stickers. It has a driver that get text file and print stickers. so I actually need to send to this driver.

Comment: Answer updated if printdialogbox is used , That may help u

Comment: What is it the PrintDialog? it unknown ?

Comment: Is that mean that the printer dialog show? because I dont want the dialog.

Comment: Now it let me save the file not print it

Comment: I wrote string fileName = @"C:\Users\o-tsoudry\Files\Tehila.txt";
            string PrinterName = @"\\rshprt04\p-RSH108";     and then your code

Comment: have u tried replacing "print" to "printto": PSI.verb = "printto"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206768/discussion-between-bhushan-muttha-and-tehila).